# Entitlement process & Milestone

Tags: casemilestone, entitlement-process

can we deploy Entitlement process & Milestone to another org. through Flosum deployment tool, If so then which component to include in snapshot to capture Entitlement Process & Milestones.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked with Flosum support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is not Flosum-specific as I suspect all vendor tools support the same metadata types

Use:

- `MilestoneType`
- `EntitlementProcess`
- `EntitlementTemplate`

plus any related metadata that these metadata types reference, e.g. BusinessHours, CustomField, `Workflow`

Consult the Metadata API Guide, for example [EntitlementProcess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_entitlementprocess.htm), to see what the related metadata can be